# Undefined property: stdClass::$menu in workbench_access_node_presave()

Tags: workbench

I'm logged in as user/1 and am using a workbench module. Whenever I unpublish a published revision (using the moderate tab) I am presented with the following errors:

```
Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$menu in workbench_access_node_presave() (line 667 of /home/mysite/public_html/sites/all/modules/workbench_access/workbench_access.module).
Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$menu in workbench_access_node_presave() (line 668 of /home/mysite/public_html/sites/all/modules/workbench_access/workbench_access.module).
Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$menu in workbench_access_node_presave() (line 667 of /home/mysite/public_html/sites/all/modules/workbench_access/workbench_access.module).
Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$menu in workbench_access_node_presave() (line 668 of /home/mysite/public_html/sites/all/modules/workbench_access/workbench_access.module).
```

There is a green tick next to - The live revision of this content has been unpublished.
and then there is a Warning message as well:
Currently there is no published revision of this node.

How do I prevent these messages from appearing? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Sorry to be a pain, but this is a module issue and as a result should be moved to the Workbench Access [issue queue](http://drupal.org/project/issues/workbench_access?categories=All)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are the administrator - as the administrator it is good to be able to see errors.

However - lower the error log level in settings.conf.

```
$conf['error_level'] = '0';
```

[Discussion on error logs](http://www.drupalcoder.com/blog/disable-error-reporting-to-the-screen-on-a-production-site-in-drupal)  :

> Go to Administer > Site configuration > Error reporting
>   (admin/settings/error-reporting). There you have a dropdown list under
>   'Error reporting' with the two choices you have for the error logging,
>   being: Write errors to the log. Write errors to the log and to the
>   screen.